# What is the highest score obtainable in Pac-Man?

Tags: arcade, pac-man

What is the highest score possible, if you eat all the dots, all the fruit and all the monsters?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The maximum possible score in Pac-Man is 3,333,360 points, achieved by eating every single dot, energizer blob, flashing blue ghost and fruit on 256 boards.  [This has been achieved several times since 1999](https://www.twingalaxies.com/game/pac-man/arcade/points-factory-speed/page/1).

Comment: Pity. 27 points too many.

Comment: just as a pointer for intrested people passing though, you can see **why** that is, here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/185772/why-is-3333360-the-maximum-score-in-pac-man/185776#185776

Answer (score -6):

The highest score possible is 333,333,360 if you eat all the ghosts in the first 18 levels and eat all items in all levels. And the nine dots in the kill screen(level 256) board.

Comment: This doesn't add anything new to a question that's nearly 8 years old

Comment: Where do these extra 330 million come from that aren't in the other answer?